# Fixed Position CSS

Tags: html, css

On my website, I have a div beneath my header with some quick links.  I am using http://davidwalsh.name/persistent-header-opacity to keep that div on-screen at all times.  However, I want it to show at the top (`position:fixed;top:0px;`, but only once the original place has been passed.  In other words, I don't want it sticking to the top until the user has scrolled past it.  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript by listening for the scroll event and responding with a style change based on the scroll position:

```
var nav = document.getElementById('hmenus'); 
var navTop = nav.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function(e) { 
  var scrollY = window.scrollY ? window.scrollY : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (navTop < scrollY) {
    nav.style.position = 'fixed'; nav.style.top = 0;
  } else { 
    nav.style.position = ""; nav.style.top = "";
  }
}
```

​
`#hmenus` is a stackoverflow element, so you can try it right here in Firebug. :-)

Comment: You'll want to capture the default offset outside of the if statement, otherwise, if you set its position to fixed with a top of 0, it will continually be comparing 0 to the scroll position.

Comment: Works for me, Robert. (I just added an edit for IE compatibility.)

Comment: It works when you scroll down, but when you scroll back up it sticks until you hit the top of the window.

Comment: Got it, thanks: I didn't even notice that. :) I guess this answer is the same as yours now, except without jQuery...

Answer (score 4):

1. On page load create a variable containing the default top offset of the menu.
2. Monitor the scroll event, if scrollTop > that original top offset, make the position fixed, otherwise static.
3. Profit.

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/49gPT/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for it with new approach.

use `position:sticky` to follows the scroll.

Here is the article explained.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

and old way of doing this [demo](http://jsbin.com/omanut/2)

with [sticky position demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)